# Div to Wrap Content?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get all the the content in my page to be wrapped by a 100% wide div, so I can place 100% wide divs below it.  Basically I want a 100% wide header div (which I have) and a 100% wide footer div.

I have been trying for HOURS to get it, but I'm sure I'm missing something here??
http://sammybutts.com/mud2/events.html - You'll see the green header... I would like something similar on the bottom.

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance for any input!

**Clarification - Just to clarify, I would like to basically put width:100% divs after the close of `<div id="content-wrap">`

Comment: Try to reproduce the error in Jsfiddle.  Most won't click on that external link.

Comment: Please include your relevant code (HTML and CSS in this case)

Comment: Just add another div after the `content-wrap` div...it will be automatically 100% wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic markup for this would be:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">..</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">..</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">..</div>
</div>
```

The css for this markup would be something like this:

```
#header, #footer {
     width:100%; //already is set to 100% because default display is block
}
.wrapper {
    margin:0 auto; //center the element
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 720px; //scale down the element so you can center it.
}
```

Don't add `float` to one of these elements. This works great for me I use it as default.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content-wrap"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

The CSS

```
#header{width:100%;}
#content-wrap{width:100%;}
#footer{width:100%;}
```

Comment: I would recommend using an external stylesheet too.

Comment: When a div is default `display: block`, why would you give it a width of 100%?